# Realm 5.8.0: findAllSorted - compile error

Tags: android, realm

Android Studio 3.2.
Realm: 4.1.0

In my **build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {  
    ext.REALM_VERSION = '4.1.0'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$REALM_VERSION"      
    }
}
```

In my **app/build.gradle:**

```
implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
```

Here snippet:

```
RealmQuery<Merchant> realmQuery = realm.where(Merchant.class);
return realmQuery.findAllSorted(sortByFieldName, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

And this code success work. Nice.

But when I upgrade Realm to **5.8.0** I get compile error:

```
Error:
error: cannot find symbol
                return realmQuery.findAllSorted(sortByFieldName, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: Because it was replaced by `realmQuery.sort(sortByFieldName, Sort.ASCENDING).findAll()`

Comment: Also if you upgrade to 5.x, you need to update realm-android-adapters to 3.0.0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> `realmQuery.findAllSorted(sortByFieldName, Sort.ASCENDING)`

Is replaced by

`realmQuery.sort(sortByFieldName, Sort.ASCENDING).findAll()`

since 5.0.0

---

See change log:

> 5.0.0 (2018-03-15)
>
> **Breaking Changes**
>
> - The OrderedCollectionChangeSet parameter in OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener.onChange() is no longer nullable.
>     Use changeSet.getState() instead (#5619).
> - realm.subscribeForObjects() have been removed. Use `RealmQuery.findAllAsync(String subscriptionName)` and
>     `RealmQuery.findAllAsync()` instead.
> - Removed previously deprecated RealmQuery.findAllSorted(), RealmQuery.findAllSortedAsync(), RealmResults.distinct() and
>     RealmQuery.distinctAsync(). Use `RealmQuery.sort()` and `RealmQuery.distinct()` instead.

Please note that this change also demands updating to `realm-android-adapters 3.0.0`.